# Compute and Data transfer not happening concurrently in cuda Streams on Iteration 2

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvcc, nsight, cuda-streams

I have written a basic program where a chunk of data is loaded in CPU memory (Pinned), and then I transfer it in chunks to GPUs (Asynchronously), and then do computation on each chunk. So for each chunk, I have created a stream.
**The issue I am facing is data transfer of the second chunk and computation on the first chunk are not happening concurrently, they are happening sequentially.** For all other chunks, it is happening concurrently.

Any suggestion on how I can a get second the transfer of the second chunk and computation on the first chunk concurrently?

I have uploaded screenshots of two traces (One for 5 iterations and another for 10 iterations).

(This is on a 16GB V100, tried on nvcc 11.7 and 12.3)

5 Chunks:
[image: trace for 5 Chunks]
10 Chunks:
[image: trace for 10 Chunks]

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "driver_types.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
using namespace std;

#define checkCudaErrors(err)                                                     \
    do                                                                           \
    {                                                                            \
        if (err != cudaSuccess)                                                  \
        {                                                                        \
            std::cerr << "CUDA error at " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " \
                      << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;                   \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                  \
        }                                                                        \
    } while (0)

__global__ void intialize_mark(char *mark, uint32_t num_e)
{
    uint32_t j;
    j = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    j = j * 512 + threadIdx.x;
    if (j >= num_e)
        return;
    mark[j] = 0;
}

__global__ void intialize_mask(char *mask, uint32_t num_e)
{
    uint32_t j;
    j = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    j = j * 512 + threadIdx.x;
    if (j >= num_e)
        return;
    mask[j] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    cudaFree(nullptr);
    uint32_t numIterations = 10;
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(0);
    std::cout.tie(0);

    uint32_t numNodes = 1000000;
    uint64_t numEdges = 20000000;

    uint64_t *edgelist;
    cudaHostAlloc(&edgelist, numEdges * sizeof(uint64_t), cudaHostAllocDefault);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> dis;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < numEdges; i++)
    {
        edgelist[i] = dis(gen);
    }

    uint32_t num_threads = 512;                   // -> number of threads per block
    uint32_t num_blocks_n = (numNodes / 512) + 1; // -> number of blocks for nodes
    uint32_t num_blocks_e = (numEdges / 512) + 1; // -> number of blocks for edges
    uint32_t nny = (num_blocks_n / 1000) + 1;     // -> y dimension for nodes
    uint32_t nnx = 1000;                          // -> x dimension for nodes
    uint32_t ney = (num_blocks_e / 1000) + 1;     // -> y dimension for edges
    uint32_t nex = 1000;                          // -> x dimension for edges

    dim3 grid_n(nnx, nny);        // -> grid for nodes
    dim3 grid_e(nex, ney);        // -> grid for edges
    dim3 threads(num_threads, 1); // -> threads per block

    uint64_t numEdgesIteration = (numEdges + numIterations - 1) / numIterations; // -> number of edges per iteration

    char *d_mark;
    char *mask;
    uint64_t *d_edgeList1;
    uint64_t *d_edgeList2;

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_mark, (numEdgesIteration) * sizeof(char)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&mask, (numEdgesIteration) * sizeof(char)));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_edgeList1, (numEdgesIteration) * sizeof(uint64_t)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_edgeList2, (numEdgesIteration) * sizeof(uint64_t)));

    cudaStream_t cudaStreamArr[numIterations];
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        cudaStreamCreate(&cudaStreamArr[i]);
    }
    uint64_t currentNumEdges;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= numIterations; i++)
    {
        if (i < numIterations)
        {
            if ((min(numEdges, (i + 1) * numEdgesIteration) - (i)*numEdgesIteration) > 0)
            {
                checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpyAsync(d_edgeList2,
                                                edgelist + (i)*numEdgesIteration,
                                                (min(numEdges, (i + 1) * numEdgesIteration) - (i)*numEdgesIteration) * sizeof(uint64_t),
                                                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,
                                                cudaStreamArr[i]));
            }
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            currentNumEdges = min(numEdges, (i)*numEdgesIteration) - (i - 1) * numEdgesIteration;

            intialize_mark<<<grid_e, threads, 0, cudaStreamArr[i - 1]>>>(d_mark, currentNumEdges);

            intialize_mask<<<grid_e, threads, 0, cudaStreamArr[i - 1]>>>(mask, currentNumEdges);
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        swap(d_edgeList1, d_edgeList2);
    }
}
```

I also tried using 3 streams (1 for HostToDevice, 1 for DeviceToHost and another for Computation). Still same issue.

Comment: there is no guarantee that two commands issued to different streams will run concurrently.

Comment: Try running your code with `CUDA_MODULE_LOADING=EAGER ./my_app`.  If that fixes the issue, see the writeup [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/persistent-kernel-does-not-work-properly-on-some-gpus/264019/5).

Comment: The lazy loading issue is also [documented in the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-execution).

Comment: @paleonix  @robert-crovella  using `CUDA_MODULE_LOADING=EAGER` works, Thanks